# running from console is ok, from Eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm going crazzy with Eclipse. I writing simple test class which uses external jar. which uses native library .dll
When I Running from Eclipse, command Run.
Here my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\YAZ\bin\yaz4j.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at org.yaz4j.Connection.<clinit>(Connection.java:56)
    at ru.Test.testConnection(Test.java:20)
    at ru.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

But when I run this code from console like this

```
java -cp "bin;C:\Program Files\YAZ\java\yaz4j.jar" ru.Test
```

Everything works perfect!
It's the same code. **How is it works in console and not works in Eclipse?**

here how I plugin this referenced jar to my project in Eclipse:
[image]

Comment: nice handmade circles!!!

Comment: check the run configuration?

Comment: and what should be in run configuration? I've write in run config like this: -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\YAZ\bin" it doesn't help...

Comment: i meet this problem too,, can you find the way to solve it?

Comment: @sendreams unfortunately after an year of trying finding the solution, the question is still open.
I've found my way to work around this inconvenience. See link in my answer. "Remote debugging" should help.

Comment: @miroque, in my own computer everything is ok, but in a windows server2003 envirment, there problem will be occur. BTW, thank you for your  answer.

Answer (score 0):

The messages you get when native methods fail to link are dreadful. I can think of several root causes that might give this message:

1. The DLL isn't loading some other dependent DLL when loaded from Eclipse. This is governed by the Windows PATH environment variable, which could be different when you're running in Eclipse.
2. It's a 32-bit DLL, and you're running with a 64-bit JVM under Eclipse, but 32-bit from the command line (or vice versa.)

Comment: About second point, it's all 32-bit. Not that problem. It's more to first point, about PATHs. cause it works from console and i write needed pathes to PATH. So how to do the same to Eclipse? or how to check what PATH uses eclipse?

Comment: If you launch Eclipse from CMD.EXE, then the PATH eventually seen by the program should be the same one you can see in CMD.EXE using "set PATH".

Comment: nope, launching from cmd.exe didn't help... it starts like ordinary program

Comment: in debug i've found that with this command `-Djava.library.path="${env_var:PATH}` eclipse see all needed PATHes. So I guess it native library cannot make call to function further in Eclipse running environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with exactly the same problem for some days now trying to use the YAZ toolkit in my project. The thing was that native libraries get loaded correctly on various test computers, but not on my personal PC.

**In short:** the cause of the problem is that the JVM loads the incorrect **libxml2.dll** and **libxslt.dll** dependent libraries.

When I launch the JVM from the IDE, it starts looking in the following places for the native libraries:

1. (jdk_home_dir)\jre\bin. Somehow this step is **skipped** on all other test computers when loading dependent libraries (other than the main yaz4j.dll). This way the test computers don't load the wrong dll's.
2. (jdk_home_dir)\bin
3. if you set the -Djava.library.path parameter, it will look in that dir at this step
4. %SystemRoot%\system32
5. %SystemRoot%
6. The working directory set for the project, if any. This step is **skipped** on my personal PC, for unknown reasons, but works on all other test computers.
7. the %path%

I have figured out this by using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Note that steps 1 and 2 may be interchanged.

The YAZ toolkit main DLL named **yaz4j.dll** makes secondary calls to other dll's in the toolkit: **libxml2.dll** and **libxslt.dll** (among others).
 My JVM finds them in the **(jdk_home)\jre\bin** directory. They seem to be bundled with Java and they are obviously different from the ones in the YAZ toolkit.
That means that procedures that are being called by yaz4j.dll could not be found in those dll's. This way the UnsatisfiedLinkException is thrown.

My JVM seems to be always searching firstly for native libraries in **(jdk_home)\jre\bin** regardless of the environment %path% variable or the -Djava.library.path switch.
Replacing the dll's in that dir may break some JVM native functionality so I wouldn't recommend that.

So the last step that needs to be done is to figure out how to make the JVM load the correct **libxml2.dll** and **libxslt.dll** libraries.

Recompiling **yaz4.dll** to make it point to renamed **libxml2.dll** and **libxslt.dll** might be a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, you need to have JDK not JRE build path library